# Bootstrap image not showing in background of three columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show an image full width in the background of three columns. I thought if I wrapped the three columns in a div and put a background on the div, it would happen, but it's not showing.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/BT0SWRh3aq

Here's my code:

```
                <div id="bg-pink-data-points">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>RESEARCH</h3>
                <p>The systematic investigation into and study of materials and sources in order to establish facts and reach new conclusions</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>WRITE</h3>
                <p>Mark (letters, words, or other symbols) on a surface, typically paper, with a pen, pencil, or similar implement.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>DISCOVER</h3>
                <p>In order to protect access to your account, we need to know who you are. Please provide details about the Primary cardmember as well as your Discover card</p>
            </div>
                </div>
```

Here's css:

```
    #bg-pink-data-points {
    background: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpapers-for-Background-HD-Wallpaper-1080x607.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div is not getting assigned any value for height. You can either set this to a fixed height or I recommend just changing the css slightly and adding a wrapper class like row or col-xs-12.

CSS Change:

```
     #bg-pink-data-points {
            background-image: url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Wallpapers-for-Background-HD-Wallpaper-1080x607.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

HTML Change:

```
    div class="row" id="bg-pink-data-points">
```